# Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "could not find function "%>%"" in R parallel programming

Tags: r

Every time I run the script it always gives me an error: Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "%>%""

I already check every post on this forum and tried to apply it but no one works.

Please advise any solution.
Please note: I have **only 2 cores** on my PC.
My code is as follows:

```
library(dplyr) # For basic data manipulation
library(ncdf4) # For creating NetCDF files
library(tidync) # For easily dealing with NetCDF data
library(ggplot2) # For visualising data
library(doParallel) # For parallel processing

MHW_res_grid <- readRDS("C:/Users/SUDHANSHU KUMAR/Desktop/MTech Project/R/MHW_result.Rds")


# Function for creating arrays from data.frames
df_acast <- function(df, lon_lat){
  
  # Force grid
  res <- df %>%
    right_join(lon_lat, by = c("lon", "lat")) %>%
    arrange(lon, lat)
  
  # Convert date values to integers if they are present
  if(lubridate::is.Date(res[1,4])) res[,4] <- as.integer(res[,4])
  
  # Create array
  res_array <- base::array(res[,4], dim = c(length(unique(lon_lat$lon)), length(unique(lon_lat$lat))))
  dimnames(res_array) <- list(lon = unique(lon_lat$lon),
                              lat = unique(lon_lat$lat))
  return(res_array)
}
# Wrapper function for last step before data are entered into NetCDF files
df_proc <- function(df, col_choice){
  
  # Determine the correct array dimensions
  lon_step <- mean(diff(sort(unique(df$lon))))
  lat_step <- mean(diff(sort(unique(df$lat))))
  lon <- seq(min(df$lon), max(df$lon), by = lon_step)
  lat <- seq(min(df$lat), max(df$lat), by = lat_step)
  
  # Create full lon/lat grid
  lon_lat <- expand.grid(lon = lon, lat = lat) %>% 
    data.frame()
  
  # Acast only the desired column
  dfa <- plyr::daply(df[c("lon", "lat", "event_no", col_choice)], 
                     c("event_no"), df_acast, .parallel = T, lon_lat = lon_lat)
  return(dfa)
}
# We must now run this function on each column of data we want to add to the NetCDF file
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 2)
prep_dur <- df_proc(MHW_res_grid, "duration")
prep_max_int <- df_proc(MHW_res_grid, "intensity_max")
prep_cum_int <- df_proc(MHW_res_grid, "intensity_cumulative")
prep_peak <- df_proc(MHW_res_grid, "date_peak")
```

Comment: I see nothing here that attempts to use `parallel` or `foreach`, other than the registration function that would make them possible. Regardless, you load `dplyr` in the local process only, you likely need to explicitly tell `parallel` to load it in the other processes as well.

Comment: @r2evans `daply` does. I can't believe that people still use plyr. I'm getting nostalgic over this.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Roland. Okay, from `?daply`, I think you need to add `.paropts` with options to `foreach` that will load your required packages.